# How to add images and videos in cassandra's (Queries to include image)?

Tags: database, nosql, cassandra, pycassa

In cassandra how to add images in column family for a row. Below I mentioned a sample table which shows the  KEY,Name,Age and Cover_Image.
[image]

Here we can able to add Name,Age by entering the queries like this

> create column family users with comparator=UTF8Type
>              and column_metadata=[
>       {column_name:Name,validation_class:UTF8Type},
>       {column_name:Age,validation_class:LongType,index_type:KEYS}];
>
> set users[babu][Name]='Babu Droid';
>
> set users[babu][Age]=23;

Like the above queries, what's the query to add an image (query for both create(also validation_class) and set options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an image you would want to use BytesType for the column validator and simply insert the raw bytes of the image into the column. There won't be a good way to do something like that from the command line interface though. You would need to write some custom code using a client library.